# Unable to access React component in HTML page if it is kept in a separate JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I have a React component in a JavaScript file and I added it in my HTML page as: `<script type="text/babel" src="component.js" />`

Here is the `ReactComponent` code:

```
var ReactComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div id={this.props.uniqueId}></div>
        );     
    }
});
```

Then I am using the component in rest of the code of my HTML page like:

```
<script type="text/babel">
    ReactDOM.render(<ReactComponent uqId='id1'/>,
                    document.getElementById('container'));
</script>
```

However after deploying the code to the server and running it, I am getting the error `ReactComponent is not defined`. Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Note: If I keep the component in the HTML file itself it works fine. Also there are no problems with the JavaScript file downloading and `browser.min.js` is added into the HTML page.

Comment: Are you trying to use the component before including it?

Comment: No, I have file adding script tag way before using it in the page. But I am using that component multiple times. Is it a problem? Thanks.

Comment: No that shouldn't be a problem. Is the React lib included on the page? And this is only happening once on the server, not a problem on your local?

Comment: I only added react.min.js, react-dom.js, browser.min.js, react-component.js. In local I cannot download script file with type text/babel as its not served by http, data, etc.. Thats why I should test it in server only

Comment: It sounds like a problem in your deploy process. How you do it? For some reason, your "component.js" file isn't being loaded. Check the "Network" on your browser DevTools to see if it's being downloaded.

Comment: Its getting downloaded with 304 status.